# What does the symbol in the Andor logo represent?

Tags: star-wars, andor

The title logo for *Star Wars: Andor* includes a symbol I don't remember seeing before:

[image: "Andor" title logo, including an unidentified symbol]

It seems similar to the [Alliance starbird](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rebel_Alliance_starbird), and like the [Jedi Order symbol](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Order), [Sabine's tag](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Starbird_(symbol)), and the [Partisan symbol](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Saw%27s_symbol), might be intended as an in-universe precursor of the Rebel emblem. Has it been addressed yet what this is or where it comes from?

Comment: For completeness, honorable mention for Cylon fighter (new Battlestar Galactica)

Answer (score 12):

An activity guide on starwars.com describes it as a "symbol of rebellion":

[image: A pumpkin showing the three-pronged symbol from Andor]

> *Andor* is lighting up our screens on Disney+, and now the burgeoning rebellion can illuminate your front porch as well this Halloween! This *Andor*-inspired pumpkin stencil, **featuring the symbol of rebellion** from the series, is super easy. And, best of all, you don’t have to worry about keeping things neat. Keep the edges of the carved symbol jagged to capture the spirit of the rough-around-the-edges rebellion.

<sub>Source: https://www.starwars.com/news/andor-jack-o-lantern; emphasis added</sub>

No other information seems to have been provided yet (though maybe it's a bronze SF&F badge?)

[image: Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange bronze badge logo]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's supposed to be a sort of less formed, 'unfinished' Starbird. The show is about the birth of the Rebellion as we know it, and it's lacking in any military support. The logo is thinner, less imposing, more pointed, you could call it more low-key or even subtle-- just like the Rebellion is at this stage.

Comment: Can you support this interpretation with evidence from an official source?